# Zlib decompress data from websocket

Tags: python, websocket, zlib

I am exploring websocket which is sending data encoded in `zlib` the parameter of endocing is `zlib-stream`. I wanted to use `zlib` library but it seems not to work.

```
import zlib

print(zlib.decompress(text.encode()))
```

It throws me an error
`zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`. It is a discord url `wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=json&v=8&compress=zlib-stream`.
This is an example, binary message: `wp0KLShOhRZ6FibUSIWgpRPGpuCZaCNqpULQIgFLYNIGlt2UFEcGwyQVAgAAAP//`

Comment: Provide the first ten bytes of the stream in hex in your question.

Comment: Assuming that that is Base64 encoded, there is no zlib, gzip, or deflate data in that message.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create [decompression object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompressobj) and decompress every message from the start.
You can't just decompress an arbitrary message.

```
decompress_obj = zlib.decompressobj()
for compressed_message in messages:
    message = decompress_obj.decompress(compressed_message)
```